# Xamarin: How and where to i specify design aspects?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm new to xamarin forms (but familiar with WPF) and want to create a rather simple material-design app (currently android-only, but want to add IOS support later).

Even after hours of googling I have no idea where to specify the app design.

I basically started with a Xamarin Forms Crossplatform Mobile App Project and used the Master-Detail template in Visual Studio. This provides me with three projects, the "xamarin", android and IOS projects (I will call them like this from now on). Background- and logic code is currently located in the xamarin project, aswell as the basic layout for the views (button definitions, etc.).

So how do I edit the styles of the buttons, content pages, etc. to match the material design (Background colors, shape, etc.)?
There seem to be two options:

1) Define colors, styles and themes in the Android project (Resources/values/colors.xml and styles.xml files).

2) Define colors, styles and themes in the Xamarin projects xaml files (App.xaml, [pages].xaml files).

Which of these options is the way to go? What do you recommend?

I assume to have more styling options available if going for 1), but then I will have to specify every style separately for android aswell as for IOS. If specifying it in the shared xamarin project, I will only have to do it once for all platforms. 
Am i right?

What are pro's and con's / is there completely other way of doing this?

Comment: Are you using xamarin native or xamarin forms ?

Comment: I planned using xamarin forms to make it easier to deploy on android and ios

Comment: Go with the second option which is always good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting your colors, styles, and themes in the `App.xaml` file of your "Xamarin" project is the recommended way when doing `Xamarin.Forms` projects and will probably be the best way to go. This will put all of your information in one place to allow easy editing and will allow you to reference the styles easily in your code/XAML.

I don't think it's noted in the docs, but you can also use Xamarin's `OnPlatform` setters to set different iOS and Android values.

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/application) for info about global styles and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform) for information about `OnPlatform`.